# How to make my sprite shoot fireballs (bullets) in pygame?

Tags: pygame

This is my Sprite1.py program which I import to my main.py program. It contains all the classes I use in my main.py. I tried to create bullets based on a program I saw online but it doesn't work for me. Could anyone help me figure out how to successfully make it work? I don't know how to add the Bullet class from my Sprite.py program to the main.py one.

```
import pygame
import sys
import os
import time
import random
from pygame import mixer
from pygame.locals import *

def showStartScreen(surface):
    show = True
    while show == True:
        startbg = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('images', 'Starting_scr.png'))
        surface.blit(startbg, (0,0))
        pygame.display.flip()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                show = False

pygame.init()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    '''
    Spawn a player
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        super().__init__()
        self.movex = 0
        self.movey = 0
        self.frame = 0
        self.images = []
        self.imagesleft = []
        self.imagesright = []
        self.alpha = (0,0,0)
        self.ani = 4 # animation cycles
        for i in range(1,5):
            img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('images','hero' + str(i) + '.png')).convert()
            img.convert_alpha()
            img.set_colorkey(self.alpha)
            self.imagesright.append(img)
            self.image = self.imagesright[0]
            self.rect  = self.image.get_rect()
            #self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
            self.all_sprites = all_sprites
            self.add(self.all_sprites)
            self.bullets = bullets
            self.bullet_timer = .1
        for i in range(1,5):
            img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('images','hero' + str(i) + '.png')).convert()
            img = pygame.transform.flip(img, True, False)
            img.convert_alpha()
            img.set_colorkey(self.alpha)
            self.imagesleft.append(img)
            self.image = self.imagesleft[0]
            self.rect  = self.image.get_rect()
            #self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
            self.all_sprites = all_sprites
            self.add(self.all_sprites)
            self.bullets = bullets
            self.bullet_timer = .1

    def control(self,x,y):
        '''
        control player movement
        '''
        self.movex += x
        self.movey -= y
        self.bullets

    def update(self, dt):
        '''
        Update sprite position
        '''
        self.rect.center = pg.mouse.get_pos()
        self.rect.x = self.rect.x + self.movex
        self.rect.y = self.rect.y + self.movey

        # moving left
        if self.movex < 0:
            self.frame += 1
            if self.frame > 3*self.ani:
                self.frame = 0
            self.image = self.imagesleft[self.frame//self.ani]

        # moving right
        if self.movex > 0:
            self.frame += 1
            if self.frame > 3*self.ani:
                self.frame = 0
            self.image = self.imagesright[self.frame//self.ani]

        mouse_pressed = pg.mouse.get_pressed()
        self.bullet_timer -= dt  # Subtract the time since the last tick.
        if self.bullet_timer <= 0:
            self.bullet_timer = 0  # Bullet ready.
            if mouse_pressed[0]:  # Left mouse button.
                # Create a new bullet instance and add it to the groups.
                Bullet(pygame.mouse.get_pos(), self.all_sprites, self.bullets)
                self.bullet_timer = .1  # Reset the timer.


class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos, *sprite_groups):
        super().__init__(*sprite_groups)
        BULLET_IMG = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('images','fireball.png')).convert_alpha()
        self.image = BULLET_IMG
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        self.pos = pygame.math.Vector2(pos)
        self.vel = pygame.math.Vector2(0, -450)
        self.damage = 10

    def update(self, dt):
        # Add the velocity to the position vector to move the sprite.
        self.pos += self.vel * dt
        self.rect.center = self.pos  # Update the rect pos.
        if self.rect.bottom <= 0:
            self.kill()
```

This is my main.py program

```
import pygame
import os
import time
from pygame import mixer
from pygame.locals import *
import Sprite1


width = 960
height = 720

fps = 40        # frame rate
#ani = 4        # animation cycles
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.init()
main = True

pygame.init()
FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
DISLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))

surface = pygame.display.set_mode([width,height])
pygame.display.set_caption('B.S.G.!!!')
background = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('images','Bg.png')).convert()
backdropbox = surface.get_rect()
pygame.mixer.music.load('.\\sounds\\Fairy.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)


player = Sprite1.Player()   # spawn player
fire = Sprite1.Bullet()
player.rect.x = 50
player.rect.y = 500
player_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
player_list.add(player)
steps = 10      # how fast to move


Sprite.showStartScreen(surface)

while main == True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit(); sys.exit()
            main = False
        #if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:

            #if Bullet.bullet_timer <= 0:
                #Bullet.bullet_timer = 0  # Bullet ready.
                #if mouse_pressed[0]:  # Left mouse button.
                    ## Create a new bullet instance and add it to the groups.
                    #Bullet(pg.mouse.get_pos(), self.all_sprites, self.bullets)
                    #Bullet.bullet_timer = .1  # Reset the timer.

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.control(-steps,0)
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.control(steps,0)
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.rect.y -= 100

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.control(steps,0)
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.control(-steps,0)
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.rect.y += 100
            if event.key == ord('q'):
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
                main = False

    surface.blit(background, (0, 0))
    player.update()
    player_list.draw(surface) #refresh player position
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(fps)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already import the sprite file in your `main.py` on line 6:

```
import Sprite1
```

So now your code can call functions from this file:

```
Sprite1.showStartScreen( window )
```

Alternatively, instead on line 6 you could use:

```
from Sprite1 import *
```

And then your code can reference everything in `Sprite1.py` as if it was defined in the `main.py` itself.

The `import` section of the [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) makes for fairly dry reading, but might just be worth a quick look if you get stuck.

Your bullet sprite code looks mostly OK now, and should work.  It seems to be adding the newly created sprite to a `bullets` - which should be a SpriteGroup, but the supplied code does not show a definition of this.

Typically to move the bullet sprites, the code would call `bullets.update()` inside the main loop every frame.  I can see the code calling `player.update()` in the last few lines of the main loop. Maybe it just needs a similar call to `update()` for the bullets group.